# Configuring PostgreSQL on Play! 2.6

Tags: postgresql, playframework, configuration

I have a PostgreSQL(v9.6) instance running on my machine. The database is called 'postgres'. I've managed to open the application in pgAdmin 3 using localhost:5432. In my Play! application(v2.6.2) I have added the driver and the url to the application.conf file following the tutorial [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDatabase#PostgreSQL-database-engine-connection-properties) and I have added the javaJdbc dependency to my build.sbt file. So I have the following:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
db.default.username = "user"
db.default.password = "pass"
```

When I run the application though I get this error in the console:

```
Cannot connect to database [default]
```

Could somebody explain to me why this is the case? I can provide more information if I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after quite a bit of digging, it turns out the problem was actually me missing the postgres [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1200-jdbc41). If anyone encounters this problem I would suggest checking your build.sbt file and adding the org.postgres dependency if you are missing it.

This [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDatabase#postgresql-database-engine-connection-properties) on the play website doesn't explain this step.

Comment: It actually does, see: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDatabase#Configuring-the-JDBC-Driver-dependency though not specifically for Postgres.